# How to hide records from Community users based on record type

Tags: security, sharing, customer-community

I have requirement wherein i need to hide/show records from Community users based on record type i.e., Community Users should only see records of X object but only for the type of record type assigned to the Profile.

So what's happening is we have a custom object X which has two record types A and B.
Record type A is for Internal Users and records type B is for External users.
When a Internal user is creating a record with A record type External User(Community User) is able to view that record on Community.
I understand that hiding record type from Profile doesn't stop users from viewing record of that record type.
So i am confused on how to implement this.

Comment: WHat is the OWD of that Object?

Comment: OWD : Default Internal Access - Public Read/Write , Default External Access - Private.

Comment: How is external community user able to view record created by internal when OWD is private. Do you have any sharing rule in place?